# Is $n^{\log c} = c^{\log n}$ true?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

Is $n^{\log c}$ the same as $c^{\log n}$? If so, please explain.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @Matthew Conroy Yes.

Comment: Why do you think so?  Please add all your thoughts to your question.

Comment: @MatthewConroy I used wolfralpha to get a better understanding of what I am actually looking at. Then I saw on the alternative ways to write the problem you can do c^log(n) = n^log(c). Wolfrramalpha doesn't explain it so that is why I asked the question here.

Comment: Are their logarithms the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
n^{\log_b c} = \Big(b^{\log_b n}\Big)^{\log_b c} = b^{(\log_b n)(\log_b c)} = \Big(b^{\log_b c}\Big)^{\log_b n} = c^{\log_b n}.
$$